# Python Method Signature for Different Runtime Execution Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

Could someone tell me whether this idea is feasible in Python?
I want to have a method and the datatype of the signature is not fixed.

For example: 
Foo(data1, data2)      <-- Method Definition in Code

- Foo(2,3)    <---- Example of what would be executed in runtime
- Foo(s,t)    <---- Example of what would be executed in runtime

I know the code could work if i change the Foo(s,t) to Foo("s","t"). But I am trying to make the code smarter to recognize the command without the "" ...

Comment: `Foo(s, t)` is just fine as long as `s` and `t` are defined.

Answer (score 0):

[singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) might be an answer, which transforms a function into a generic function, which can have different behaviors depending upon the type of **its first argument**.

You could see a concrete example in the above link. And you should do some special things if you want to do generic dispatch on more than one arguments.